# React Native Categories Flatlist with Sub Categories

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am making a flatlist out of this data. The first 4 will be the top level of categories. When one of those 4 items are pressed, I need to generate another flatlist with the corresponding sub-category based on the parent ID. For example if the parent ID is 1 it will be a sub-category for "category1". So the first flatlist with be 4 tiles with "category1", "category2", "category3", and "category4" and when one of those tiles is pressed, a new flatlist will appear with the sub category tiles based on the parent ID.

I hope that makes sense and thanks in advance for the help!

```
   "data": {
        "categories": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "parent_id": null,
                "name": "category1",
                "slug": "category1"
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "parent_id": null,
                "name": "category2",
                "slug": "category2"
            },
            {
                "id": 3,
                "parent_id": null,
                "name": "category3",
                "slug": "category3"
            },
            {
                "id": 4,
                "parent_id": null,
                "name": "category4",
                "slug": "category4"
            },
            {
                "id": 5,
                "parent_id": 1,
                "name": "subcategory1",
                "slug": "subcategory1"
            },
            {
                "id": 6,
                "parent_id": 1,
                "name": "subcategory2",
                "slug": "subcategory2"
            },
            {
                "id": 7,
                "parent_id": 1,
                "name": "subcategory3",
                "slug": "subcategory3"
            },
            {
                "id": 8,
                "parent_id": 1,
                "name": "subcategory4",
                "slug": "subcategory4"
            },
            {
                "id": 9,
                "parent_id": 1,
                "name": "subcategory5",
                "slug": "subcategory5"
            },
            {
                "id": 10,
                "parent_id": 1,
                "name": "subcategory6",
                "slug": "subcategory6"
            },
            {
                "id": 11,
                "parent_id": 1,
                "name": "subcategory7",
                "slug": "subcategory7"
            },
            {
                "id": 12,
                "parent_id": 1,
                "name": "subcategory8",
                "slug": "subcategory8"
            },
            {
                "id": 13,
                "parent_id": 2,
                "name": "subcategory9",
                "slug": "subcategory9"
            },
            {
                "id": 14,
                "parent_id": 2,
                "name": "subcategory10",
                "slug": "subcategory10"
            },
            {
                "id": 15,
                "parent_id": 2,
                "name": "subcategory11",
                "slug": "subcategory12"
            },
            {
                "id": 16,
                "parent_id": 2,
                "name": "subcategory13",
                "slug": "subcategory13"
            },
            {
                "id": 17,
                "parent_id": 2,
                "name": "subcategory13",
                "slug": "subcategory13"
            },
            {
                "id": 18,
                "parent_id": 2,
                "name": "subcategory14",
                "slug": "subcategory14"
            },
            {
                "id": 19,
                "parent_id": 2,
                "name": "subcategory15",
                "slug": "subcategory15"
            },
            {
                "id": 20,
                "parent_id": 2,
                "name": "subcategory16",
                "slug": "subcategory16"
            },
            {
                "id": 21,
                "parent_id": 3,
                "name": "subcategory17",
                "slug": "subcategory17"
            },
            {
                "id": 21,
                "parent_id": 3,
                "name": "subcategory18",
                "slug": "subcategory18"
            },
            {
                "id": 21,
                "parent_id": 3,
                "name": "subcategory19",
                "slug": "subcategory19"
            },
            {
                "id": 22,
                "parent_id": 4,
                "name": "subcategory20",
                "slug": "subcategory20"
            },
        ]
    },
```

Comment: I don't see any question here, what **exactly** is not working?

Comment: @RubenSmn I am able to generate the first flatlist I need, but when I press on one of the tiles I am unsure on how to generate a new flatlist with the corresponding sub-categories.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the selected category in state and filter the visible items when state changes.

```
function App() {
  const [selectedId, setSelectedId] = useState<number | null>(null)
  const [items, setItems] = useState<ICategory[]>()

  useEffect(() => {
    const filtered = categories.filter(item => item.parent_id === selectedId)
    setItems(filtered)
  }, [selectedId])

  const renderItem = ({ item }: { item: ICategory }) => {
    return (
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => handlePress(item)}>
        <Text>{item.name}</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    )
  }

  const handlePress = (item: ICategory) => {
    if (item.parent_id === null) setSelectedId(item.id)
    else setSelectedId(null)
  }

  return (
    <View>
      <FlatList
        keyExtractor={(item) => item.id.toString()}
        data={items}
        renderItem={renderItem}
      />
    </View>
  )
}

interface ICategory {
  id: number;
  parent_id: number | null;
  name: string;
  slug: string;
}
```

Comment: How does this satisfy the question of "How to generate a new flatlist with corresponding sub-categories"?

Comment: When useEffect hook called, it will filter the categories array and set the items state variable to the filtered arrays, which are subcategories or the main categories. The FlatList component will then render the new list of items.

This is how to generate a new flatlist with the subcategories of the currently selected category.